# Problem pushing a value inside an array located in an object key

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have the following function:

```
const createMenu = () => {
  const obj = {
    consumption: [],
  };

  return obj;
};
```

This is a function that, when called, returns the object

```
{ consumption: [] }
```

What I am trying to do is create a key inside that object that is a function that, when called with a string parameter, it pushes the string into the array inside the key 'consumption';

Here's my attempt:

```
const createMenu = () => {
  const obj = {
    consumption: [],
  };

  let order = (item) => {obj.consumption.push(item); };
  obj.order = order;

  return obj;
};
```

The expected result is that, when calling that function inside the object with a string parameter,like this:

```
createMenu().order('pizza');
```

when I run:

```
console.log(createMenu().consumption);
```

my result is:

```
['pizza']
```

but it is not working. I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

```js
const createMenu = () => {
  const obj = {
    consumption: [],
  };

  let order = (item) => {
    obj.consumption.push(item);
  };
  obj.order = order;

  return obj;
};

createMenu().order('pizza');

console.log(createMenu().consumption);
```

Comment: A key can't be a function. You probably meant a _property_, to which a key refers.

Comment: Why would influencing a first `createMenu()` affect what a second `createMenu()` would return?

Comment: `createMenu().`  Your calling this twice, two separate instances..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You creating two instance of createMenu,
Your likely wanting to create 1

```
const menu = createMenu()
```

Also if you want to chain the functions, you will want to return the obj again inside order.

Below is an example..

```js
const createMenu = () => {
  const obj = {
    consumption: [],
  };

  let order = (item) => {
    obj.consumption.push(item);
    return obj;
  };
  obj.order = order;

  return obj;
};

const menu = createMenu().order('pizza');
console.log(menu.consumption);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the object created by `createMenu()` to a variable then perform operations to that variable. The update below should work.

In your code, you've created a new object when called the `createMenu()` function at the `console.log`. Which is not what you are wanting.

```js
const createMenu = () => {
  const obj = {
    consumption: [],
  };

  let order = (item) => {
    obj.consumption.push(item);
  };
  obj.order = order;

  return obj;
};

const menu = createMenu();
menu.order('pizza');
menu.order('burger');
console.log(menu.consumption); // ["pizza", "burger"]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for this. Set up the array in the constructor, add a method to update the array when a new menu item is introduced, and have a final method that returns your desired object.

```js
class CreateMenu {
  
  constructor() {
    this.consumption = [];
  };

  orderItem(item) {
    this.consumption.push(item);
    return this;
  }

  getList() {
    return { consumption: this.consumption };
  }

};

const menu = new CreateMenu();

const order = menu
  .orderItem('pizza')
  .orderItem('cheese sticks')
  .getList();
  
console.log(order);
```